# Bash Sed Pipe to Command One-Liner

Tags: sed, pipe

I'm trying to dump output from all of my interfaces. This is what I've got so far:

```
ifconfig | awk '{print $1}' | sed s'/.$//'
```

I'd like to have something like :

```
ifconfig | awk '{print $1}' | sed s'/.$//' | tcpdump -i {} -c 1
```

where {} is what's passed in the pipe.

UPDATE:

Here's a sample output of ifconfig:

```
em0:    encaps: ether; framing: ether
        flags=0x3/0x8000 
        curr media: i802 2:0:0:1:0:4
em0.0:  flags=0x8000 
        inet primary mtu 1500 local=129.16.0.1 dest=128.0.0.0/2 bcast=191.255.255.255
        tnp primary mtu 1500 local=17825796
```

awk will print out the interface name which I need to pass to tcpdump.

The equivalent run of the above code would be:

```
tcpdump -i em0
tcpdump -i em0.0
```

**How can I pipe out to tcpdump in one line?**

Comment: That would be correct if there were only one interface. Unfortunately ALL systems have at least 2 :)

Comment: can you provide an example output of your ifconfig and intended content of {} to tcpdump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifconfig | grep -Po "^[^\s:]+" | while read if; do tcpdump -i $if; done
# tcpdump -i em0
# tcpdump -i em0.0

tcpdump `ifconfig | grep -Po "^[^\s:]+" | sed "s/^/-i /"`
# tcpdump -i em0 -i em0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to dump output from all of my interfaces.

Is there some reason why you don't just use the special device named `any`?  IE `tcpdump -i any`.

> http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html
>   -i interface
>
> Listen on interface. If unspecified, tcpdump searches the system interface list for the lowest numbered, configured up interface (excluding loopback), which may turn out to be, for example, `eth0''. On Linux systems with 2.2 or later kernels, an interface argument of`any'' can be used to capture packets from all interfaces. Note that captures on the ``any'' device will not be done in promiscuous mode.

Comment: Good thinking, but it's not available in my version of tcpdump.

Comment: What version of tcpdump, and what OS are you running then?  That almost certainly matters a great deal, since the output of 'ifconfig' is not completely standard across all *nix systems.

Comment: -i doesn't just loop thru all interfaces. I've tried on OSX and CentOS and it errors out if I don't put an interface name